# Can't compile dpdk on archlinux

Tags: compiler-errors, archlinux, dpdk

I am trying to compile `dpdk 16.04-1` on `4.6.2-1-ARCH`. The following output is for trying to install the AUR package, but compiling myself from source following dpdk's quickstart guide gives me exactly the same errors. I recieve the following errors:

```
==> Building and installing package
==> Making package: dpdk 16.04-1 (Fri Jul 29 15:46:48 CEST 2016)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Downloading dpdk-16.04.tar.xz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10.4M  100 10.4M    0     0  9755k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 9761k
==> Validating source files with sha1sums...
    dpdk-16.04.tar.xz ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting dpdk-16.04.tar.xz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
Configuration done
==> Starting build()...
== Build lib
== Build lib/librte_compat
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_compat.h
== Build lib/librte_eal
== Build lib/librte_eal/common
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_byteorder.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_branch_prediction.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_debug.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_errno.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_launch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_log.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memory.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memzone.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_ids.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_per_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_random.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_tailq.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_alarm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_string_fns.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_version.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal_memconfig.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc_heap.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_hexdump.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_devargs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_dev.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_feature_defs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_features.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_keepalive.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_time.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_vect.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rtm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder.h
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
  CC eal.o
  CC eal_hugepage_info.o
  CC eal_memory.o
  CC eal_thread.o
  CC eal_log.o
  CC eal_pci.o
  CC eal_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_pci_vfio.o
  CC eal_pci_vfio_mp_sync.o
  CC eal_debug.o
  CC eal_lcore.o
  CC eal_timer.o
  CC eal_interrupts.o
  CC eal_alarm.o
  CC eal_common_lcore.o
  CC eal_common_timer.o
  CC eal_common_memzone.o
  CC eal_common_log.o
  CC eal_common_launch.o
  CC eal_common_pci.o
  CC eal_common_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_common_memory.o
  CC eal_common_tailqs.o
  CC eal_common_errno.o
  CC eal_common_cpuflags.o
  CC eal_common_string_fns.o
  CC eal_common_hexdump.o
  CC eal_common_devargs.o
  CC eal_common_dev.o
  CC eal_common_options.o
  CC eal_common_thread.o
  CC eal_common_proc.o
  CC rte_malloc.o
  CC malloc_elem.o
  CC malloc_heap.o
  CC rte_keepalive.o
  CC rte_cpuflags.o
  AR librte_eal.a
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_kni_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_dom0_common.h
  INSTALL-LIB librte_eal.a
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio
make[6]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.module.mk:79: recipe for target 'igb_uio.ko' failed
make[5]: *** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'igb_uio' failed
make[4]: *** [igb_uio] Error 2
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'linuxapp' failed
make[3]: *** [linuxapp] Error 2
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'librte_eal' failed
make[2]: *** [librte_eal] Error 2
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:77: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make[1]: *** [lib] Error 2
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-kunterbunt/aur-dpdk/src/dpdk-16.04/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens either because you dont have the proper kernel headers installed (version mismatch) or if it could not create proper symlinks for you.

If you are using an x86_64 machine I would recommend the make flags as `make config T=x86_64-default-linuxapp-gcc`